# SQL Concat Subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, concatenation

I would like the "user_names" to be a list of users, but I can't get multiple subquery items to be assigned to "user_names". It work's if the subquery only returns 1 item, but doesn't work if it returns multiple.

Bed Table
[id]
[1]
[2]
[3]

Assignment Table:
[id, bed_id, user_id]
[1, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 2]

Users Table:
[id, 'user_name']
[1, 'John Smith']
[2, 'Jane Doe']

```
    sql = "SELECT
        b.id,
        (
            SELECT
                u.user_name
            FROM
                assignments AS a
            INNER JOIN
                users as u
            ON
                a.user_id = u.id
            WHERE a.bed_id = b.id
        ) AS user_names
        FROM beds AS b"
```

The desired results would be:
[1, 'John Smith, Jane Doe']
[2, '']
[3, '']

I tried hardcoding the bed id and running this segment to get a list of names. It didn't work:

```
    sql = """
        (
        SELECT
            array_agg(user_name)
        FROM
            roomchoice_assignment AS a
        INNER JOIN
            roomchoice_customuser as u
        ON
            a.user_id = u.id
        WHERE
            a.bed_id = 1
        GROUP BY user_name
        )"""
```

It returned the following:

```
[
    [
        [
            "John Smith"
        ]
    ], 
    [
        [
            "Jane Doe"
        ]
    ]
]
```

I was hoping for this:

```
['John Smith, Jane Doe']
```

Comment: why not just select user_name from assignments?

Comment: Which database are you using? The method used for concatenating values are different. There will most likely be a duplicate question that addresses your question.

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: I am trying to get a list of assignments and a list of users assigned to each, so I think this is the best way to write the query. The database is Postgres.

Comment: I can't get group_concat to work

Comment: But what about the array-based `group_concat` alternatives? Show us how you tried them and what happened and you can get your question re-opened.

Comment: besides the group_concat, there was another major problem, could have been solved by left outer joins without any sub-selects because sub-selects in the select clause have to be single-valued unlike those in the from clause.

Comment: Still can't get it to work.

Comment: @maraca I just reopened it to account for the updates if you want to take a crack at it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One issue with the query you have is that you're grouping by the column you're applying array_agg on. If you remove the group by you would get `"{"John Smith","Jane Doe"}"`, but you would still be missing the bed id column, and if you want a list of all beds even if there are no assignments you should use left joins instead of subqueries (which also should be better for performance and readability).

You could use [`string_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) as indicated by the duplicate question.

This query:

```
SELECT b.id, string_agg(u.user_name, ', ') users
FROM beds AS b
LEFT JOIN assignment AS a ON a.bed_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN users as u ON a.user_id = u.id
GROUP by b.id;
```

Would give you a result like:

```
1;"John Smith, Jane Doe"
2;""
3;""
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thanks.